# jquery - How to make change function in the select box when the select box is in the loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

anyone please help me, 
I will make a table that has a number of rows and columns according to the database. but here I gave the example of 3 rows and columns only. the columns containing the form input and select box, when I use the select box then I have to take the value and storing them in an array.

I have problems when running the following code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var table = $('<table></table>').addClass('foo');
for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
  var row = $('<tr></tr>');
 for(var j=0; j<3; j++){
   var col = $('<td></td>');
     row.append(col);
      if(i==j) {
       col.append("<input id='arr_tujuan"+ i +"_"+ j +"' value='x'>");
      }
      if(i > j){
       col.append("<input id='arr_tujuan"+ i +"_"+ j +"'>");
      }
      if(i < j) {
       var selek = "<select id='arr_tujuan"+ i +"_"+ j +"' onchange='getval(this,i,j);'><option value=''>Pilih . .</option><option value='V'>V</option><option value='A'>A</option><option value='X'>X</option><option value='O'>O</option></select>";
        col.append(selek);
      } 
  }
  table.append(row);
}
$('#tablenya').append(table);
  
});
function getval(sel,k,l) {
    console.log('arr_tujuan'+k+'_'+l+' = '+sel);
    //array push
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tablenya">
<form id="fm_tujuan">
</form>
</div>
```

thank you for your help

Comment: concatenation the variable like this in change function onchange='getval(this,"+i+","+j+");'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) concatenation the variable like this in change function `onchange='getval(this,"+i+","+j+");'` if you not do it like this mean its consider as string so you have to concatenate the variable  .

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var i=0;
var table = $('<table></table>').addClass('foo');
for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
  var row = $('<tr></tr>');
 for(var j=0; j<3; j++){
   var col = $('<td></td>');
     row.append(col);
      if(i==j) {
       col.append("<input id='arr_tujuan"+ i +"_"+ j +"' value='x'>");
      }
      if(i > j){
       col.append("<input id='arr_tujuan"+ i +"_"+ j +"'>");
      }
      if(i < j) {
       var selek = "<select id='arr_tujuan"+ i +"_"+ j +"' onchange='getval(this,"+i+","+j+");'><option value=''>Pilih . .</option><option value='V'>V</option><option value='A'>A</option><option value='X'>X</option><option value='O'>O</option></select>";
        col.append(selek);
      } 
  }
  table.append(row);
}
$('#tablenya').append(table);
  
});
function getval(sel,k,l) {
    console.log('arr_tujuan'+k+'_'+l+' = '+sel);
    alert('arr_tujuan'+k+'_'+l);
    alert('here you can do your array push ');
    //array push
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tablenya">
<form id="fm_tujuan">
</form>
</div>
```